# Adding a class to children with condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('tbody[role=rowgroup] tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).has('SPAN.isclosed')) {
        $(this).find("td").addClass('isclosed');
    }
});
```

I am trying to add the class `isclosed` to all the TDs of the items that match the selector `tbody[role=rowgroup] tr` which has a child `Span` with a class isclosed.

This applies the `isclosed` to every td though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.has()` doesn't return a boolean, it returns all the elements of the collection that match the condition. Any jQuery collection is truthy.

You could write:

```
if ($(this).has("span.isclosed").length > 0)
```

but it's simpler to just just use `.has()` on the entire original collection, instead of using `.each()`.

```
('tbody[role=rowgroup] tr').has("span.isclosed").find("td").addClass("isClosed");
```

Comment: Only `if ($(this).has("span.isclosed").length > 0)` would not work unless you change the next line

Comment: @Huangism Why not? What does the next line have to change to?

Comment: That was it! a collection. arg... Thanks Barmar. Will accept answer in 4 minutes

Comment: Because `$(this).find("td").addClass('isclosed');` adds isclosed to all cells in the row. Your simpler solution is much better, changing that one line from original code won't do it

Comment: @Huangism He wants to change all cells in the row.

Comment: Maybe, now that I read the question again I am unsure if OP wants all TDs in the row or just the TDs with the span inside. I guess currently both lines does the same thing

Comment: I read it as all TDs in the row if the row has a matching span inside.

Comment: @Huangism That's what my shorter code does as well. Just the TDs with the span inside would be `$('tbody[role=rowgroup] tr td:has(span.isclosed)').addClass("isclosed")`

Comment: Yes you may be right as I read it as target all the tds which has a isclosed span, I don't know now the question was worded in a weird way. Yea i noticed that, I edited the prev comment to include that. Oh looks like that's what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

I know that this was already answered, but I wanted to present two more examples using jQuery's [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). One example uses a `boolean` as a [state](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) determining whether to add or remove a class name. The other example uses a [function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-function-state) to determine which class name to add.

```js
/* .toggleClass( className, state ) */
$('tbody[role="rowgroup1"] tr').each(function() {
    var condition = !!$(this).find('span.isclosed').length;
    $(this).find('td').toggleClass('isclosed', condition);
});

/* .toggleClass( function [, state ] ) */
$('tbody[role="rowgroup2"] tr td').toggleClass(function() {
    var condition = $(this).parents('tr').find('span.isclosed').length;
    if(condition) {
        return 'isclosed';
    }
});

/**
 * NOTE: $(this).length works with the IF statement only because
 * it returns either 0 or 1+, but you'll need a boolean for STATE.
 */
```

```css
td.isclosed {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Test Table 1</h1>
<table>
    <tbody role="rowgroup1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="isclosed">Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h1>Test Table 2</h1>
<table>
    <tbody role="rowgroup2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="isclosed">Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Demo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```